# QR code aligning

Tags: align, positioning, qrcode

tell me please how the QR code can be aligned to one of the corners?

[image]

**note:** `\qrcode[height=3cm]{https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook}` works fine, but colorful QR code not

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.0cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings, shadings}
\newcounter{fadcnt}\setcounter{fadcnt}{0}
\newcommand\fadingtext[3][]{%
\stepcounter{fadcnt}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fading letter\thefadcnt]
\node[text=transparent!0,inner xsep=0pt,outer xsep=0pt,#1] {#3};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(textnode.base)]
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,#1](textnode){\phantom{#3}};
\shade[path fading=fading letter\thefadcnt,#2,fit fading=false]
(textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newbox\shbox
\tikzset{%
path picture shading/.style={%
path picture={%
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}%
\pgfgetlastxy\pathwidth\pathheight%
\pgfinterruptpicture%
\global\setbox\shbox=\hbox{\pgfuseshading{#1}}%
\endpgfinterruptpicture%
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{center}}%
\pgftransformxscale{\pathwidth/(\wd\shbox)}%
\pgftransformyscale{\pathheight/(\ht\shbox)}% \dp will (should) be 0pt
\pgftext{\box\shbox}%
} } }
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{rainbow}{10bp}{color(0bp)=(violet);
color(1.6667bp)=(blue);
color(3.3333bp)=(cyan);
color(5bp)=(green);
color(6.6667bp)=(yellow);
color(8.3333bp)=(orange);
color(10bp)=(red)}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,yshift=0pt,xshift=0pt]%
at (current page.north west)
{\fadingtext[scale=0.5]{path picture shading=rainbow}{\qrcode[height=3cm]{https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\fadingtext[scale=0.5]{path picture shading=rainbow}{\qrcode[height=5cm]{https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simply that the anchor for the node is its centre, and so your QR code is offset by that amount. So you just need to shift it back into the right position. Since you're loading the `calc` library from TikZ, this can be done easily with a coordinate calculation in the `at (...)` part of your code.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.0cm,top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings, shadings}
\newcounter{fadcnt}\setcounter{fadcnt}{0}
\newcommand\fadingtext[3][]{%
\stepcounter{fadcnt}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fading letter\thefadcnt]
\node[text=transparent!0,inner xsep=0pt,outer xsep=0pt,#1] {#3};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(textnode.base)]
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,#1](textnode){\phantom{#3}};
\shade[path fading=fading letter\thefadcnt,#2,fit fading=false]
(textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);%
\end{tikzpicture}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newbox\shbox
\tikzset{%
path picture shading/.style={%
path picture={%
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}%
\pgfgetlastxy\pathwidth\pathheight%
\pgfinterruptpicture%
\global\setbox\shbox=\hbox{\pgfuseshading{#1}}%
\endpgfinterruptpicture%
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{center}}%
\pgftransformxscale{\pathwidth/(\wd\shbox)}%
\pgftransformyscale{\pathheight/(\ht\shbox)}% \dp will (should) be 0pt
\pgftext{\box\shbox}%
} } }
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{rainbow}{10bp}{color(0bp)=(violet);
color(1.6667bp)=(blue);
color(3.3333bp)=(cyan);
color(5bp)=(green);
color(6.6667bp)=(yellow);
color(8.3333bp)=(orange);
color(10bp)=(red)}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at ($(current page.north west)+(.75cm,-.75cm)$) 
    {\fadingtext[scale=0.5]{path picture shading=rainbow}
    {\qrcode[height=3cm]{https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook}}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: No, the QR code still cannot be scanned, so it is not correct, am I right?

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh Sorry, it was shifted off of the page since the anchor of the node is its centre. I've updated the code to shift it inwards.

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh But now I realize that was your problem in the first place, so the box is not needed.

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but I thought that there is a variant without manual placing like (.70cm,-.75cm), but if not it is a good answer